# Error while inserting into db in php

Tags: php

I am trying to inserts some values to the database in my php program but I am getting the error

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in C:\wamp\www\php\books.php on line 9
```

mysql_query..

```
mysql_query("insert into books values('$_GET["title"]','$_GET["author"]','$_GET["edition"]','$_GET["publish"]','$_GET["isbn"]',)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That's a PHP error not a SQL error. You have a syntax error in your PHP. Specifically on line 9. Probably missing a semicolon or a dollarsign before your variable

Comment: I see single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: Also, look into SQL injection.

Comment: Also look into http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

get your values in variables like

```
$title = $_GET["title"];
$author = $_GET["author"];
```

then use query like this

```
mysql_query("insert into books values('$title','$author','$edition','$publish','$isbn',)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using nested double quotes

```
mysql_query("insert into books values('{$_GET["title"]}','{$_GET["author"]}','{$_GET["edition"]}','{$_GET["publish"]}','{$_GET["isbn"]}',)") or die(mysql_error());
```

or

```
mysql_query("insert into books values('$_GET[title]','$_GET[author]','$_GET[edition]','$_GET[publish]','$_GET[isbn]',)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

The good query is :

```
mysql_query("insert into books values('" . $_GET["title"] . "','" . $_GET["author"] . "','" . $_GET["edition"] . "','" . $_GET["publish"] . "','" . $_GET["isbn"] . "')") or die(mysql_error());
```

There are non escaped quotes but also a comma which has nothing to do here, at the end of the query.
Maybe you should learn PHP and its syntax first.